# I am getting the error System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid operation given the current state of the object.'

Tags: c#, oracle

When the code is working and it reaches the part where it performs a Commit, it is where the error appears

I have seen solutions where a modification must be made to the Webconfig in the appsettings section, however, is there no other solution that does not have to do with modifying the Webconfig?

This is the code where the error appears, exactly in the Commit

```
 public ErrorCode insertNC(EntidadesNC data)
        {
            var errorCode = new ErrorCode();
            DbConnection DataConnection = ConnectionGet(enuTypeDataBase.OracleVTime);
            DbTransaction tran = null;

            try
            {
            DataConnection.Open();
            tran = DataConnection.BeginTransaction();

            foreach (var item in data.ListainsertNC)
                {
                    if (errorCode.P_COD_ERR == 0)
                    {
                        errorCode = insertNCV2(item, DataConnection, tran);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorCode.P_COD_ERR = 1;
                errorCode.P_MESSAGE = ex.ToString();
                ELog.save(this, ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (errorCode.P_COD_ERR == 0)
                {
                    tran.Commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    tran.Rollback();
                }

                if (DataConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) DataConnection.Close();
            }

            return errorCode;
        }
```

This is the code where the function insertNCV2 is called

```
public ErrorCode insertNCV2(itemNC data, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction tran)
        {
            List<OracleParameter> parameter = new List<OracleParameter>();
            var response = new itemNC();
            var errorCode = new ErrorCode();
            var sPackageName = ProcedureName.pkg_paymentNC + ".SP_PRUEBA_PAYROLL";

                try
                {
                    parameter.Add(new OracleParameter("P_NID_COTIZACION", OracleDbType.Int64, data.P_NID_COTIZACION, ParameterDirection.Input));
                    parameter.Add(new OracleParameter("P_NRECEIPT", OracleDbType.Varchar2, data.P_NRECEIPT, ParameterDirection.Input));
                    parameter.Add(new OracleParameter("P_SCODCHANNEL", OracleDbType.Int64, data.P_SCODCHANNEL, ParameterDirection.Input));

                    //OUTPUT
                    OracleParameter P_COD_ERR = new OracleParameter("P_COD_ERR", OracleDbType.Int32, 9000, errorCode.P_COD_ERR, ParameterDirection.Output);
                    OracleParameter P_MESSAGE = new OracleParameter("P_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 900, errorCode.P_MESSAGE, ParameterDirection.Output);


                    parameter.Add(P_COD_ERR);
                    parameter.Add(P_MESSAGE);

                    OracleDataReader odr = (OracleDataReader)this.ExecuteByStoredProcedureVT(sPackageName, parameter);

                   // ELog.CloseConnection(odr);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errorCode.P_COD_ERR = 1;
                    errorCode.P_MESSAGE = "Hubo un error al insertar los sub items de las coberturas"; // ex.ToString();
                    ELog.save(this, ex.ToString());
                }

            return errorCode;
        }
```

I am thankful for any kind of help :)

Comment: Firstly, don't commit in _finally_, do this in the body of the try. You only want to commit if there were no errors.

Comment: In your logic you have lots of error handling code, when you see this error, what other information have you captured in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

`InvalidOperationException` with database operations generally indicates that the connection has been *closed* or *aborted* before your line of code executes.

The other scenario with *transactions* is if the *transaction* was never started. With Transactions things are a bit easier, we don't need to rollback a transaction on an exception, many exceptions raised during DB operations will abort the transaction anyway, closing the connection without an explicit `Commit` will also effectively rollback the transaction.

- Use Rollback to revert back to a transaction check point, not to *cancel* or *abort* the transaction.

Moving the commit logic might help you to debug this:

```
public ErrorCode insertNC(EntidadesNC data)
{
    var errorCode = new ErrorCode();
    DbConnection DataConnection = ConnectionGet(enuTypeDataBase.OracleVTime);
    DbTransaction tran = null;

    try
    {
        DataConnection.Open();
        tran = DataConnection.BeginTransaction();

        foreach (var item in data.ListainsertNC)
        {
            if (errorCode.P_COD_ERR == 0)
            {
                errorCode = insertNCV2(item, DataConnection, tran);
            }
        }

        if (errorCode.P_COD_ERR == 0)
        {
            tran.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            tran.Rollback();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorCode.P_COD_ERR = 1;
        errorCode.P_MESSAGE = ex.ToString();
        ELog.save(this, ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (DataConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) DataConnection.Close();
    }

    return errorCode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in this case I followed your advice to move the structure to try to debug this, however I still get the same thing.

Comment: What is the response to `insertNCV2`? is that an error state? Also please indicate the specific line of code where it fails. Then set a break point at that line and check the current status of the connection before the line of code executes. Some types of exceptions in `insertNCV2` can result in the connection being aborted. So please provide all the error information and logs so that we can assist you